# Anyway to make stick USB work again?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I've been partitioning, formating, mounting and unmounting a stick usb for yesterday. The last thing I know about it it's it was working, but today when I woke up to go ahead with what I was doing, I run into USB doesn't work anymore, `/dev/sdc` is not available.

dmesg when I disconnet the device

```
[  832.086249] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

dmesg when I connect the device again

```
[  849.641605] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  849.771226] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  849.771230] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  849.771232] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 12021559020039
[  849.771357] usb 1-6: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[  849.771361] usb 1-6: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[  849.771692] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  849.771874] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
```

The device seems to correspond to ID `090c:1000`

```
optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d62:001c Darfon Electronics Corp. Benq X120 Internet Keyboard Pro
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsblk` and `fdisk -l` doesn't recognize it anymore

```
optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  37,3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0   7,8G  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0 732,4G  0 part /home
└─sdb2   8:18   0    20G  0 part

optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d3018

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    78125094    39061523+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2        78127102    85938175     3905537    5  Extended
/dev/sda3        85938176   102322175     8192000    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda5        78127104    85938175     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e378f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1536002047   768000000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2      1536002048  1577945087    20971520   83  Linux
optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $

optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdc: No such file or directory

optimus@optimus-desktop ~ $ sudo testdisk /dev/sdc
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device /dev/sdc
```

Anyway to get it work again? thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried formatting it on another machine?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, no, I didn't, I'll bought a new stick usb and then I'll try installing Windows 10, just to see if it's possible to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to repair the usb using mkusb**

I have also encountered such a problem due to repeated formatting and mounting. Then I used [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to repair my device.

Plugin your USB and start mkusb. It will detect your device and will give you a number of options. Select "restore to a standard storage device" and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @optimus, if mkusb does not work (at once), you may find useful tips at the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035